# Implementing a REST API that uploads a document and it's information to the drive and database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-drive

I want to develop an applications where users (students in my university) can upload documents (some sort of a GUI for the drive). I have a Vue application and a NodeJS server which is used as a REST API. Basically, the user should fill the form in the client side. It contains information like the course number, semester, etc. The most important part is the document that the user uploads. The client side should pass this information to the backend and the backend should do:

1. Upload the document into the Google Drive.
2. Upload the document's information into the Firebase Firestore database (as well as the ID of the document that he got from step 1).

The structure in the Google Drive is: `/documents/$course_number/$document` where `$course_number` is the course number and `$document` is the uploaded document.

In my backend I have the following files:

- File `server.js` - start the server.
- File `routes.js` - contains the routes of the API.
- File `utils.js` - contains different general functions.
- File `drive.js` - sort of a class of the Drive.
- File `database.js` - sort of a class of the database.
- File `logger.js` - contains the configurations of the log4js.

The one file that I would like to get a review on is the `routes.js` files (but for the compliance I'll add others as well). The `routes.js` looks like:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const utils = require('./utils.js');
const logger = require('log4js').getLogger('routes');
const drive = require('./drive.js');
const database = require('./database.js');

router.post('/new-document', function(request, response) {
  var document_file = request.files.document_file;
  var course_information = {
    "course_number": request.body.course_number,
    "semester": request.body.semester,
    // Others info here (not important)
  };
  var document_filename = utils.getDocFilename(course_information);
  drive.getFolderIDByName(course_information.course_number).then(folder_id => {
    if (folder_id == null) {
      drive.createFolder(course_information.course_number, [DRIVE_DOCUMENTS_ID]).then(folder_id => {
        if (folder_id == null) {
          // Throw exception
        }
        drive.uploadFile(document_filename, document_file.mimetype, utils.bufferToStream(document_file.data), [folder_id]).then(document_id => {
          if (document_id == null) {
            // Throw exception
          }
          course_information.document_id = document_id;
          database.uploadRecord(FIREBASE_COLLECTION_DOCUMENTS, course_information).then(res => {
            response.status(200).json({ message: "success"});
          }).catch(e => {
            var error_message = "Failed to upload record to Firebase: " + e;
            logger.error(error_message);
            response.status(500).json({ error: true, message: error_message });
          });
        }).catch(e => {
          var error_message = "Failed to upload file to the Drive: " + e;
          logger.error(error_message);
          response.status(500).json({ error: true, message: error_message });
        });
      }).catch(e => {
        var error_message = "Failed to create a new folder in the Drive: " + e;
        logger.error(error_message);
        response.status(500).json({ error: true, message: error_message });
      });
    } else {
      drive.uploadFile(document_filename, document_file.mimetype, utils.bufferToStream(document_file.data), [folder_id]).then(document_id => {
        if (document_id == null) {
          // Throw exception
        }
        course_information.document_id = document_id;
        database.uploadRecord(FIREBASE_COLLECTION_DOCUMENTS, course_information).then(res => {
          response.status(200).json({ message: "success"});
        }).catch(e => {
          var error_message = "Failed to upload record to Firebase: " + e;
          logger.error(error_message);
          response.status(500).json({ error: true, message: error_message });
        });
      }).catch(e => {
        var error_message = "Failed to upload file to the Drive: " + e;
        logger.error(error_message);
        response.status(500).json({ error: true, message: error_message });
      });
    }
  }).catch(e => {
    var error_message = "Failed to get Folder ID by name from the Drive: " + e;
    logger.error(error_message);
    response.status(500).json({ error: true, message: error_message });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

A few notes about the `routes.js`:

- I really don't like how it's nested. It's probably the most important thing that bothers me, regarding my code. I couldn't figure a way to wait for the promises, other than with `.than` and `.catch`.  I would move all the code after the `drive.getFolderIDByName...` part into a separate script called `genericQuerices` but then I would have to pass the `response` as parameter, because I can't figure a way to wait for the promises to finish (I need to call `response.status(200)...` at the end.
- Google API makes it really difficult to check if folder exists (again, I'll need to use additional `.then` and `.catch`). The `DRIVE_DOCUMENTS_ID` contains the id of the `/documents` which is sort of constant but ideally, I need to get the ID, when I start the server and then somehow pass this variable from `server.js` to `routes.js`. Not sure if it's a good idea, or I should just look for it, for each query.
- The REST API gets the file as Buffer and the Google API requires a stream so I'm using the `bufferToStream` to convert it (Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089230/how-to-convert-buffer-to-stream-in-nodejs)).
- The `getDocFilename` method just constructs the filename of the document that will be used inside the Drive.
- Should I return status `500` in case of error, for example if the Drive failed to upload the file? Maybe other status code?
- I want the `drive.js` and `database.js` be most generic as possible (to be scalable). They should contain the code of the drive and the database only.

The `server.js` looks like:

```
const cors       = require("cors");
const express    = require("express");
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

const routes     = require('./routes');
const logInit    = require('./logger');

const path = __dirname + '/../public/';

logInit();

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path));

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8080"
};

app.use(cors());

const MAXMUM_FILE_SIZE = 50;
app.use(fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: MAXMUM_FILE_SIZE * 1024 * 1024 },  // Maximum = 50 MB  
}));

app.use('/api', routes);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8081;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

The `drive.js`:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const logger = require('log4js').getLogger('drive');

var drive_instance = null;

var drive = {
  getDrive: function() {
    if (drive_instance == null) {
      this.initDrive();
    }
    return drive_instance;
  },

  initDrive: function() {
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });
    drive_instance = google.drive({
      version: 'v3',
      auth: oauth2Client,
    });
  },

  getFolderIDByName: async function(name) {
    logger.info("Looking for the folder ID of " + name);
    const query = `name = '${name}' and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`;
    const response = await this.getDrive().files.list({
      'q': query,
      'pageSize': 1000,
      'fields': "files(id, name)"
    });
    if (response.status != 200 || response.data.files.length == 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return response.data.files[0].id;
  },

  createFolder: async function(name, parents) {
    logger.info("Creating a new folder " + name + " under " + parents);
    const resource = {
      'name' : name,
      'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
      'parents': parents
    };
    const response = await this.getDrive().files.create({ 'resource': resource });
    if (response.status != 200) {
      // Throw exception
    }
    return response.data.id;
  },

  uploadFile: async function(name, mimetype, stream, parents) {
    logger.info("Uploading a new file " + name + " of type " + mimetype + " under " + parents);
    const requestBody = {
      'name': name,
      'mimeType': mimetype,
      'parents': parents
    };
    const media = {
      'mimeType': mimetype,
      'body': stream,
    };
    console.log({ 'requestBody': requestBody, 'media': media });
    const response = await this.getDrive().files.create({ 'requestBody': requestBody, 'media': media });
    if (response.status != 200) {
      // Throw exception
    }
    return response.data.id;
  }
};

module.exports = drive;
```

The `database.js` file:

```
const firebase = require("firebase");

var database_instance = null;

var database = {
  getDatabase: function() {
    if (database_instance == null) {
      this.initDatabase();
    }
    return database_instance;
  },

  initDatabase: function() {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    database_instance = firebase.firestore();
  },

  uploadRecord: async function(collection, data) {
    const response = await this.getDatabase().collection(collection).add(data);
    return response; // TODO: Should I return response or Boolean?
  }
};

module.exports = database;
```

The code works well and as you can see it's mostly implemented (I need to add a few exceptions in some places). Is it possible to review my code, especially the `routes.js` file?